# Contact Form 7 submit without page refresh

Tags: page-refresh, contact-form-7, prettyphoto

I'm working on a wordpress website with Contact Form 7 plugin.
When someone click on a button(trigger), contact form 7 open in prettyPhoto popup box. Upon click on submit button, popup close automatically. If there are some errors on form submission, sender can't see the errors because popup box automatically closed due to page refresh.

Is there any way to stop closing the popup box or stop page refresh and popup box remain open after submission of form so user can see the form response/errors?

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED: Finally I got it. Usually when we use Contact Form 7 on web pages, ajax form initialization function is executed on page load. In this case I've to use cf7 shortcode in popup box so form html will render in popup box after clicking on a link. (initialization scripts were loaded but didn't initialize the form for ajax because form was not exist on the page). 
Solution is, load cf7 javascript files and call $('form').wpcf7InitForm(); function after form is rendered.

```js
 $(".fancybox").fancybox({
  'padding'       : 0,
  'maxWidth'   : 660,
  'autoHeight' : true,
  afterLoad: function () { 
   $.getScript('http://domain.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/jquery.form.min.js');
   $.getScript('http://domain.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js');
   $('form').wpcf7InitForm(); // Initialize form for AJAX
   $.fancybox.update();
   return;
  },
 });
```

Comment: Did you solve this with the official prettyPhoto plugin? I can't find a function called "fancybox" or something where I can set an afterLoad event.

Comment: I get Uncaught TypeError: $(...).wpcf7InitForm is not a function

Comment: @LaurenceCope make sure that the function gets called after your form is loaded. 
1- load the form
2- load the script plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js
3- call the function wpcf7InitForm()

Comment: Am using Magnific Popup so in the open callback I enter the following, but looks like scripts.js is not loaded as it does not recognise the function:
      open: function() {
    $.getScript('http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/jquery.form.min.js');
    $.getScript('http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js');
    $('form').wpcf7InitForm(); 

    return;
      },